# Are Fastreport 1.5.2 compatible with .Net Framework 4.8?

Tags: .net, fastreport

Please, could you tell me is FastReport 1.5.2 compatible with .Net 4.8 ?

I am trying to do make some reports, but some functionality don't work for example the print button.

I would be very thankful If somebody knows what is the problem.